# Power BI connectivity issue with Oracle 10.2g

Tags: oracle, powerbi-desktop

I have installed Oracle 10.2g and Power BI on my laptop
but im facing an issue to connect Power BI with Oracle 10.2g on local machine
Please see below error.. advise that how to resove it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jJrV.png)

Comment: Can you copy the error text to your post so this can be helpful to more users? Thank you!

Comment: Oracle 10g is ancient - like 20+ years old - and no longer supported by Oracle. Based on the error it would appear that Power BI just doesn't support the connection. Not sure if the link they offer would provide a supported driver or not. Did you investigate the link and what it had to offer? Is it possible to use a version of Oracle that is more current, like 19c (minimum) or 23c?